# setbuf(stdin,NULL) not working in my code

Tags: c

My requirement is to keep my input buffer size to zero. So to make my input buffer size zero I have used setbuf(stdin,NULL) function but then also the buffer isn't modified it seems.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    setbuf(stdin,NULL);
    int RollNo,Class;
    char Name[15],Comments[15];
    printf("Enter RollNo: ");
    scanf("%d",&RollNo);
    puts("Enter Name: ");
    fgets(Name,15,stdin);
    printf("Enter Class:");
    scanf("%d",&Class);
    puts("Enter Comments: ");
    fgets(Comments,15,stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried using fflush(stdin) and it worked. Kindly help me to clear the input buffer with setbuf(stdin,NULL) or setvbuf() functions.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What is the purpose or reason?

Comment: @Fe2O3 I am practicing to clear the input buffers

Comment: Looks like you're experiencing problems by mixing calls to `scanf()` with calls to `fgets()`... Is that the issue?

Comment: @Fe2O3 I have used fgets() so that I can use spaces in between the inputs

Comment: Your actual problem here is that `scanf("%d",&RollNo);` leaves a new line character `'\n'` in stdin and that trips `fgets`. Simply add a `getchar();` line after the `scanf` to discard the new line character and everything will work as expected. Do not use `fflush(stdin)` since that's undefined behavior and without any guarantees.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer)

Comment: Note that setting a stream to be unbuffered is not the same as clearing it. See: [How can I clear an input buffer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7898215/2505965)

Comment: @Oka I know that scanf() leaves a new line character in the input buffer but I need to use setbuf(stdin,NULL) t clear the input buffer

Comment: @Lundin I want to use setbuf(stdin,NULL( function to clear the input buffering

Comment: `setbuf(stdin,NULL)` will not sort `\n` problem. `fflush(stdin)` is implementation-defined (or maybe even UB)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue to use `scanf()`, you need to read and understand the documentation for the function.

Below is an example responding to "*want to include spaces*" in strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {

    int RollNo,Class;
    char Name[15],Comments[15];

    printf("Enter RollNo: ");
    scanf(" %d",&RollNo); // Notice: " %d", not "%d"

    printf("Enter Name: ");
    scanf(" %14[^\n]",Name); // How to read 14 chars into a 15 byte buffer

    printf("Enter Class:");
    scanf(" %d",&Class);

    printf("Enter Comments: ");
    scanf(" %14[^\n]",Comments); // Same as above.


    printf( "\n%d : %s : %d : %s\n", RollNo, Name, Class, Comments );
    return 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
Enter RollNo: 27
Enter Name: John H Begood
Enter Class: 23
Enter Comments: Nice Guy

27 : John H Begood : 23 : Nice Guy
```

There are many improvements to this example. First off would be to check that each call to `scanf()` was able to assign as many variables as the program expected. This all is for another day.

Go study the manual and you'll learn that there are LOTS of variations you can explore...

Beginners should EITHER stick to `scanf()` or go on to master `fgets()` and the supporting library functions that can turn digits into numbers, etc...

Comment: I need to use setbuf(stdin,NULL) or setvbuf() functions for clearing the input buffers. Can you show me on using that ?

Comment: You've not give a reason for this _need_... I've written this working demonstration that achieves the stated objective ("spaces in strings"). Frankly, I don't see why you think unbuffering the input will change things in any way! "_clearing the input buffers_" That is not the purpose of these two functions!